# Data display GUI with multi threading Python

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, data-acquisition

I'm basically simulating acquiring data from the serial port and plotting it on a graph displayed in a GUI which is made using Tkinter. The incoming serial data is simulated by a simple while loop which calculates a sine function and adds the value to a queue which is size 100, the data generating part of the program is written under the class named *DataThread*

```
import Tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from collections import deque
import threading 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg 
from time import sleep

class DataThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ISCONNECTED = 1
        self.d = deque(maxlen=100)

    def run(self):
        t = 1        
        while True:
            wave = np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t*0.001)
            self.d.append(wave)
            print(wave)
            t = t+1
            sleep(1)
            if self.ISCONNECTED == 0:
                break
```

The other class generates the GUI , it creates an instance of the *DataThread* class and calling the function *start_d* should start the thread which generates the data. I would like to stop the thread by pressing the stop button but I'm not sure how to stop the thread.

```
class Application(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master=None):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master) 
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W)) 


        self.fig = Figure()
        self.ax_1 = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.createWidgets()
        self.a = DataThread()

    def createWidgets(self):        

        self.frame = tk.Frame(borderwidth=5, 
                          relief="sunken", width=300, height=20)
        self.frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=4, 
                        sticky=(tk.N, tk.S, tk.E, tk.W))
        self.frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()

        self.canvas.show()


        self.namelbl = tk.Label(text="Start DAQ")
        self.namelbl.grid(column=10, row=0, columnspan=2,
                          sticky=(tk.S, tk.W), padx=5)

        self.start = tk.Button( text='Start',
                                command=self.quit)         

        self.start.grid(column=10, row=1,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)

        self.stop = tk.Button( text='Stop',
                                command=self.stop_serial)
        self.stop.grid(column=11, row=1,sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)


    def start_d(self):
        self.a.ISCONNECTED=1
        self.a.start()

    def readSensor(self):
        data2plot = self.a.d
        self.ax_1.plot(range(data2plot),data2plot)
        self.root.update()
        self.root.after(527, self.readSensor)                

    def stop_serial(self):

        self.a.ISCONNECTED=0
    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()
```

And the last part which simply runs the GUI

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    Application().run()
```

I based my code of the following question: [Dynamically updating Tkinter window based on serial data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574821/dynamically-updating-tkinter-window-based-on-serial-data) 
The difference being that both, the GUI thread and the data thread, are created simultaneously, but in my case it wouldn't work because I want to start the thread only when the start button is pressed.

Comment: What's your question? Are you just asking how to stop the thread? Start the thread?

Comment: My questions is how to start stop and reinitialize the serial thread with the GUI buttons

Comment: You should modify your question to make that more clear.