# can I create/push custom event in Tkinter python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

can I create/push custom event in Tkinter python?

in the code https://stackoverflow.com/a/10575137/933882
the redraw callback is still invoked on a  *fixed* schedule, every 100 milliseconds etc.

but is it possible to trigger the callback immediately as the external serial data is available ? from usage point of view it's probably not much different, but the mechanisms are very different.

thanks